# Rails routes for non-standard assets in a mountable engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes, asset-pipeline, rails-engines

I have a few non-standard assets (i.e. files that are not images/javascript files/stylesheets such as json and binary files) that live within a mountable engine (without `isolate_namespace`) in `app/assets/data`. I want these to be part of the asset pipeline (in the same way as e.g. images).
I can add them to the asset paths collection, e.g.

```
class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
  config.after_initialize do
    Rails.application.config.assets.paths << root.join("app", "assets", "data")
  end
end
```

and I can see in the Rails console that the assets are visible to the asset pipeline (e.g. via `Rails.application.assets[]` and `ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path`). For instance, for a file `app/assets/data/foo.json`, the `asset_path` helper in the rails console for the hosting app gives me a path `assets/foo.json`, however that path does not work, I get a

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/foo.json")
```

error.

How can I get the hosting Rails app to serve these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, this is some odd behavior with json files with specific names. The files in question are named something like `schema-[UUID].json`. Rails seems to think these are calls to some controller (even though there is no such route, nor a `schema` controller) that want json-formatted data back. When I rename the files to `[UUID]-schema.json`, they all of a sudden work.